# What is the function of the * operation in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

The Code A is from the offical sample [project](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-compose-codelabs/blob/main/AnimationCodelab/finished/src/main/java/com/example/android/codelab/animation/ui/home/Home.kt).

I don't understand what `val tasks = remember { mutableStateListOf(*allTasks) }` mean, could you tell me ?

BTW, Android Studio give me some information, you can see Image A

**Code A**

```
@Composable
fun Home() {
    // String resources.
    val allTasks = stringArrayResource(R.array.tasks)
    val allTopics = stringArrayResource(R.array.topics).toList()

    // The currently selected tab.
    var tabPage by remember { mutableStateOf(TabPage.Home) }

    // True if the whether data is currently loading.
    var weatherLoading by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    // Holds all the tasks currently shown on the task list.
    val tasks = remember { mutableStateListOf(*allTasks) }

    ...
}
```

**Image A**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Kotlin `*` is the Spread Operator.
From [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs) :

> When you call a vararg -function, you can pass arguments individually, for example asList(1, 2, 3). If you already have an array and want to pass its contents to the function, use the spread operator (prefix the array with *):
>
> ```kotlin
> val a = arrayOf(1, 2, 3)
> val list = asList(-1, 0, *a, 4)
> ```

In this case `tasks` will contain the list of strings from `R.array.tasks`

Answer (score 3):

From [the documentation of varargs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs):

> When you call a vararg -function, you can pass arguments individually, for example asList(1, 2, 3). If you already have an array and want to pass its contents to the function, use the spread operator (prefix the array with *):
>
> ```java
> val a = arrayOf(1, 2, 3)
> val list = asList(-1, 0, *a, 4)
> ```

As you see, it expands an array to multiple values for use in a vararg. If you havd an array containing the elements `1, 2, 3`, you can pass `*yourArray` to a method that is equivalent to `yourMethod(1,2,3)`.